# Looking to restrict the length of a string in Java

Tags: java

I'd like to count the amount of characters within a string, and cut off any excess characters of the string. I thought of just using a while loop and a char, but I need to pass in a string. I also tried to use the remainder function, but I"m pretty sure it wouldn't work.

So, essentially, a counter for a string and then to limit that string to x amount of characters.

If I were to set the string to a single character, say

```
String x = "*";
```

Then implemented a counter in a for loop...

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
???
}
```

Would that work? I feel like it wouldn't, and that it would just be more effective for me to declare

```
char x = 'a';
```

...

I'm trying to make this as vague as possible so that I can take ideas and implement them so it's not like I'm stealing anybody's code for homework, I just need a little help.

Comment: I'm having trouble deciphering what your goal is, and also what your question is.  Can you state clearly what you're trying to accomplish (use examples), what you have tried, and how we can help?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to establish a limit in the length of a string. You can do that with String.substring(0, maxLength)

Comment: When you read the answers, below, keep in mind that you can not change the length of a Java `String`.  String objects are _immutable_ (i.e., their values can never change).  What you can do is create a _new_ String that is shorter than the original given String.

Comment: So, what I want is to create a chunk of code that a) records the amount of characters within a string and b) limit and excess characters in the string, but manually.

Comment: Coming from a C perspective...
All I've seen is people call functions from libraries, but the .length thing is something I'm familiar with.
@mevqz could you explain what the String.substring(0, maxLength) does/is?

Answer (score 2):

```
String myString = "myString";
int maxLength = 3;
if (myString.length() > maxLength)
     myString = myString.substring(0, maxLength);
```

Result will be "myS"

Comment: Uh, so, I have no clue how to do format these comments, so bear with me, please.

Is the .length function the same as if I were to declare an array, named myArray, then print myArray.length?

Comment: @Zeklaus `String` in Java is not an array, and should not be treated like array. It is fully-featured object with its methods and properties and should be treated so. `String#length()` returns how many characters does the string have.

Answer (score 0):

"I was searching around on the web for a manual code to count the amount of characters within a string, and then to a further extent cut off any excess characters of the string."

Count amount of characters within a string:

```
int length = stringName.length();
```

Cutting off extra characters of the string

```
int maxAmount; //wherever you want to stop
if(length > maxAmount)
{
    stringName = stringName.substring(0,stopPoint);
}
```

Comment: `stringName.length()` will give you the number of `char`s in a string which is usually, but not always the same as the number of characters.   Java stores text in UTF-16 encoding, and some single Unicode _code points_ occupy two `char`s.  (I'm not even going to attempt to disucss the relationwhip between code points and "characters" here).

Comment: I'm not quite familiar with what you said, but if I were limited to the 26 letters in the English alphabet and numbers 0-9, would any of these characters occupy more than one space?

I'm assuming that these special cases are going to be the unique characters in the alphabet, though.

Comment: Definitely not. All letters A-z upper case or lower case will work as well as every number.